# python regex not behaving as i think it should

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to sort through a some files using regex expression.

I have a file which contains the two following lines

```
NET "MBC_ADR_I1<1>" LOC = "R2";
NET "GP_O<7>" LOC = "R20";
```

I am using the following expression to get one of the lines only

```
f2MatchLoc = re.search('(LOC)[ ]+=[ ]+["]?({})'.format(f1LocValue), f2Line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

where `f1LocValue = R2`. However I'm getting a match on both lines.

I've tried to enter the same expression here
[regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uK4rK5/2)

which shows that my argument should be correctly formatted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f2MatchLoc = re.search(r'(LOC)[ ]+=[ ]+["]?({}\b)'.format(f1LocValue), f2Line, re.IGNORECASE)
                                              ^^
```

You need to use `\b` after `R2` so that there are no partial matches. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eN2oM9/2). Also use `r` or `raw` mode.

Comment: This r'(LOC)\s+=\s+"?({}\b)' works. thank you. however why does '(LOC)\s+=\s+"?({}\b)' not work (i removed the 'r' at the beginning)

Comment: @Ephreal python considers `\b` as an escape sequence and it will have a meaning of it as own.So `\b` will not be left for regex engine.So you use `r` or `raw` mode telling python to not apply its own escape sequqnces

Answer (score 1):

Because you have no conditions how the string should end.

```
'(LOC)[ ]+=[ ]+["]?({})'
                       ^??
```

So it matches anything that starts with `LOC = "R2`. Following are all valid search results

```
LOC = "R2 
LOC = "R2asd
LOC = "R2121
LOC = "R2   "
```

Simply, you can use double quotes or semicolon to identify end of search string. Also you can replace `\s` for white-space capturing and you can remove `[]` around single element lists

```
r'(LOC)\s+=\s+"?({})"?;'
```

Comment: using r'(LOC)\s+=\s+"?({})"?' still gives me both hits.

Comment: @Ephreal Did you check the value of the `f1LocValue` that you use in regexc string formatting. And did you run this in a loop or something?

Comment: `?` means 0 or 1, so R20 still matches, as it's R2 followed by no `"`. If you left on the `;` it would likely work

Comment: @GP89 it should evaluate as `r'(LOC)\s+=\s+"?(R2)"?;'` so `R2;"` or `R2;` should be matched but `R20` should not since after R2, it will wait for either `";` or `;`, not anything else...

Comment: I would beleve your suggestion should work. It was also what I did to begin with and is working on the regex101 site. However I only got it to work with the suggestion from vks.

Comment: @FallenAngel I know you're right. I was pointing out @Ephreal's first comment where the `;` was left off

Comment: @GP89 ahh ok a misunderstanding (: